# Let x and y be integers where f(x, y) = 5 if x < y and f(x, y) = f(x-y, y+2) + m if x >= y. Express the following relations in their simplest forms.

Tags: functions, relations

Im trying to calculate this but I am having problems trying. Help?

Let x and y be integers where f(x, y) = 5 if x < y and f(x, y) = f(x-y, y+2) + m if x >= y.

Express the following relations in their simplest forms.
a. f(2, 7)
b. f(5, 3)
c. f(15, 2)

Answer (score 0):

a) Since $2<7$, then $f(2,7) = 5.$

b) Since $5>3$, then $f(5,3) = f(2,5)+m = 5+m$

You can try the last one for yourself :)